# Unable to generate UUID id with data.sql

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Without `data.sql` everything works.

I'm using Spring Boot 2 and H2 database.

But when I'm trying to initialize the `author` table using `data.sql` I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement: insert into author (`name`) values ('Pushkin')
```

Here is the `Author` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    //getters/setters/constructors
}
```

Here is `data.sql`:

```
insert into author (`name`) values ('Pushkin');
```

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#random_uuid

Answer (score 2):

The UUIDGenerator only works when you store entities with JPA/Hibernate.

When you do plain SQL in data.sql Hibernate is not used. 
You have to follow the suggestion of JB Nizet http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#random_uuid

Answer (score 0):

first of all please check that you have tick auto increment in database for id which want to generate and then write below in @ID,
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). it will make your id unique.